# React Native to fetch from a REST API won't work because of hyphen

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework

My fetch returns this promise which works for other fields in the API but I need to save the value for a field within that has the name "datasets-pollencheck_apiaries" however react-native inteprets the "-" as something else and I can't access this field, and continually get the error that says "Can't find variable: pollencheck_apiaries"

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    LINK = responseJson.links.datasets-pollencheck_apiaries;

})
```

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is because JavaScript thinks you're trying to do a math operation. You can also access object properties with bracket notation.

You should try this:

```
LINK = responseJson.links['datasets-pollencheck_apiaries']
```

## Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Answer (score 0):

try to change to

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
    LINK = responseJson.links["datasets-pollencheck_apiaries"];

})
```